# Generate a nested HashMap List from Bidimensional Array

Tags: java, loops, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I want to group the `array_list`, if its the same companyID the services `("POSID", "POSCODE", "POSTEXT")` should be grouped to the parent.

```
public List<HashMap<String,Object>> getList(String [][] array_list) {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> data = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

        /* Example Content String [][] array_list

             {  {"4470", "ZONE A", "20", "13", "1", "3800", "Cleaning the table"},
                {"4470", "ZONE A", "20, "13"", "2", "3600", "Washing the car"},
                {"4470", "ZONE  A", "20", "13", "3", "3900", "Preparing the food"},
                {"4480", "ZONE B", "10", "9", "1", "3600", "Washing the car"},
                {"4480", "ZONE B", "10", "9", "2", "4000", "Dish Washing"},
                {"4490", "ZONE C", "5", "4", "1", "3600", "Washing  the car"},
                {"4490", "ZONE C", "5", "4", "2", "3900", "Preparing the food"}
              };
        */

        String[] company_fieldnames = new String[] { "COMPANYID", "SECTOR", "AMOUNT", "SIZE" } ;
        String[] services_fieldnames = new String[] { "POSID", "POSCODE", "POSTEXT" } ;

        for (int i = 0; i < array_list.length; i++) {

            HashMap<String, Object> parent = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            HashMap<String, Object> child = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            for (int j = 0; j < company_fieldnames.length; j++) {
            parent.put(company_fieldnames[j], array_list[i][j]);
            }

            for (int k = 0; k < services_fieldnames.length; k++) {
            child.put(services_fieldnames[k], array_list[i][k + company_fieldnames.length]);
            }

            // TODO 
            //If same Company ID (4470) then the services should be grouping and pass to the parent element   

            parent.put("services", child);
            data.add(parent);
        }

        return data;
    }
```

**Result for one company should looks like:**

```
 [  
       {  
          "COMPANYID":"4470",
          "SECTOR":"ZONE A",
          "AMOUNT":"20",
          "SIZE":"13",
          "services":[  
             {  
                "POSID":"1",
                "POSTCODE":"3800",
                "POSTEXT":"Cleaning the table"
             },
             {  
                "POSID":"1",
                "POSTCODE":"3600",
                "POSTEXT":"Washing the car"
             },
             {  
                "POSID":"3",
                "POSTCODE":"3900",
                "POSTEXT":"Preparing the food"
             }
          ]
       }
    ]
```

Comment: There are two obvious problems in the code: (1) There is only one object for the variables `parent` and `child`. Because you only clear, you use always the same collection. (2) Strings must not be compared with == if you want to compare the values (not the identity). If you need additinal help, please post the desired result!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited my post and it should be more clear. I know the problem with the HashMap collection and I have problems for reinitalizing it.

Comment: Although I implemented a ""solution"", I hesitate to post it, because what you are doing there is at least questionable, and likely does not make sense. First of all: When there is an entry with `COMPANYID:4470, SECTOR:ZONE A`  and one with the same ID but `ZONE B`, should this result in ONE entry? Why do you store the `SECTOR` at all, when its contents does not have any meaning?  Second, more importantly: Is there any reason to *not* create classes called `Service` and `Company`, and model this data structure properly? This `Map<String, Object>`  approach is likely to cause headaches...

Comment: As you can see all with the same `COMPANYID: 4470` has also the same `SECTOR, AMOUNT, AND SIZE` value, so its able to group this element. Only the last 3 elements in the array are different and should be grouped. So I guess u can publish your solution. Thanks. ;)